# Isolating dependencies in Silverlight unit tests

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0

I'm in the process of writing an LOB application in Silverlight and I'm a little dismayed by all the roadblocks I'm hitting with unit testing.

- PRISM uses a lot of extension methods, which are essentially static methods so not mockable.
- All the mocking frameworks that use dirty tricks to mock non-virtual and static methods don't work in Silverlight (e.g. Moles, JustMock.  Not sure about TypeMock Isolator.)

So, my question:

**Is there a strategy for isolating dependencies in Silverlight unit tests?**

Am I missing something, or just not thinking about this problem correctly?  Can I use UI tests (such as those available in the new VS2010 Feature Pack 2) to work around this problem?

TIA

Comment: A developer who appreciates testing and has just embarked on Silveright. Welcome to frustration :)

Comment: I figured I was barking up a dead tree... Let's hope the Gu has a good story for us tomorrow!

Comment: @herz:  It really did help me, never fear :)  You called out the areas of separation, which helped me think about *how* to test, which will help me isolate properly.  Thankfully, my client is amenable to purchasing Mr. Osherove's Typemock, which should help considerably.

Comment: all right, now I can go see Naples in peace, thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at other MVVM frameworks then if you have such issues with Prism? Usually, all layers of a Silverlight application should be testable.

- Models should be testable because they shouldn't have anything to do with any UI technology
- View models should be testable because they shouldn't reference anything on the UI
- Views (XAML) are declarative
- You'll need to fill some gaps and write your own controls, attached properties and behaviors. You can look at the Silverlight Toolkit source code to see how they handle testing there.

Answer (score 0):

you might check out silverunit (mentioned in second half of this video)
[Unit Testing in Silverlight with SilverUnit](http://www.osherove.com/videos/2009/8/25/unit-testing-in-silverlight-silverunit-and-ms-sliverlight-te.html)

Comment: Thanks Roy, I downloaded Typemock and I'm working on evaluating it and SilverUnit.  I can't seem to find the VS2010 project template on the codeplex site, was it removed?